# Why can't JavaScript read more than 3 keys at times?

Tags: javascript, html

I have an array of keys that stores which keys are being pressed. Whenever I press the left arrow, spacebar, and the up arrow together, the array will only keep two of the keycodes, leaving one not to be pushed into the array. When these three keys are pressed, the character is supposed to move left, jump up, and shoot a bullet. One of those three actions won't occur. I am using Google Chrome, and I don't know what will happen on other browsers.

```js
var $c = $('canvas');
var ctx = $c[0].getContext('2d');
var x = 20;
var y = 150;
var keys = [];
var bulletX = x + 2;
var bulletY = 0;
var bullets = [];
var face = 1;

function plr() {
  ctx.fillStyle = 'black';
  ctx.fillRect(x, y, 20, 20);
}

$c.keydown(function(e) {
  if (_.includes(keys, e.which) === false) {
    keys.push(e.which);
  }
});
$c.keyup(function(e) {
  _.pull(keys, e.which);
});

function shoot() {
  bullets.forEach(function(bullet) {
    ctx.fillStyle = 'red';
    ctx.fillRect(bullet.bX, bullet.bY, 8, 4);
    if (bullet.direction === 0) {
      bullet.bX -= 7;
    }
    if (bullet.direction === 1) {
      bullet.bX += 7;
    }
    if (bullet.bX > 700 || bullet.bX < 0) {
      _.pull(bullets, bullet);
    }
  });
}

setInterval(function() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 700, 500);
  if (keys.includes(32)) {
    bullets.push({
      direction: face,
      bX: x + face * 12,
      bY: y + 8
    });
  }
  if (keys.includes(37)) {
    face = 0;
    x -= 3;
  }
  if (keys.includes(38)) {
    y-=3;
  }
  if (keys.includes(39)) {
    face = 1;
    x += 3;
  }
  plr();
  shoot();
}, 30);
```

```css
.canvas {
  background-color: #a3c2ba;
  outline: none;
  border: #fff;
  margin: auto;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  top: 50px;
  border-radius: 0px;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Game</title>
  <script src='https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js'></script>
  <script src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.11/lodash.min.js'></script>
</head>

<body>
  <canvas class='canvas' width='300' height='200' tabindex='1' />
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: If this is happening when all three keys are pressed simultaneously, the problem is [likely your keyboard](https://superuser.com/q/1445219).

Comment: Try adding `console.log()` to the `keydown` handler, to see if it's running when you press the third key.

Comment: @AuxTaco It's not simultaneous. I wait a little bit and the problem still occurs

Comment: you'll get better results on this site if you reduce your issue to a minimum verifiable example

Comment: @bryan60 I minimized it as much as I could... All the code is to show what happens when you press the buttons. But I will attempt to minimize a little more.

Comment: Running your snippet I'm able to press all three buttons fine, all three actions seem to occur. If the problem is not your keyboard, you may need to give more detailed steps to reproduce. Also note that  pressing space before left or right will cause an error as you haven't set an initial value for `face`.

Comment: @face what browser are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have concluded that this is a problem with my keyboard. I tried this on my brother's computer and it worked fine. Thanks to everyone who attempted to help though!